# Sandcastle with just MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, sandcastle

I'm trying to auto-generate a documentation of my solution with sandcastle help file builder.

So I downloaded the following nuget-Packages:

```
<package id="EWSoftware.SHFB" version="2017.5.15.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="EWSoftware.SHFB.NETFramework" version="4.7" targetFramework="net46" />
```

I then tried to generate the documentation with msbuild by editing the csproj-File:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <ComponentPath>..\packages\ewsoftware.shfb.netframework.4.7</ComponentPath>
   <SHFBROOT condition=" '$(SHFBROOT)' == '' ">..\packages\ewsoftware.shfb.2017.5.15.0\tools\</SHFBROOT>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When doing this, I get errors that the Build(-Documentation)-Task does not support the Parameters-Property and "The SandcastleBuilder.Utils.MSBuild.BuildHelp-Task could not be initialized with its parameters".

Now I wonder if I am doing it wrong or if it is not possible to generate a sandcastle doc with just msbuild and without having a sandcastle-project in the solution at all?

Can anyone help me out?